# Java - Removing char at

Tags: java, string, char, indexof

I don't think I have a firm understanding of why -1 works in this code: is it just a place marker allowing the program to continue to run? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class RemovingChar {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        String str = "Looking out the window of my small apartment";
        String remove = "aeiou";


        String x = " ";

        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = str.charAt(i);

            if(remove.indexOf(c) == -1)
            {
                x+= c;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the [docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) & see if you can figure it out.

Comment: ... and/or step through with the debugger and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

[public int indexOf(int ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

Answer (score 1):

-1 means `Character` Not found in the  given `String`.

In [**docs**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) its clearly written :

> if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove.indexOf(c) == -1
```

if `c` will not appear in `remove` string returns `-1`

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf()` returns the index of the matched string... or **-1** if not found.

e.g.

if your string is **"hello"** then the index of **"ello"** is **1** (because it's found at position 1).

or

if your string is **"hello"** then the index of **"bla"** is **-1** (because it's not found and so `indexOf` returns **-1**)

Reference is at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Answer (score 0):

-1 is returned by the method `indexOf` if the parameter character is not in the `remove` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
   StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder(yourstring);
   strB.deleteCharAt(yourstring.length() - 1);

   System.out.print( strB.toString());
```

if you want to make a JButton will work like Backspace here's a [Tutorial](http://javaextreme.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/make-a-backspace-button/)